# ConditionalOnMissingBean by name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have multiple datasource beans defined in my configuration file.I have 2 beans named customerDataSource. I want one of them to be instantiated only if other bean is not loaded.I was trying to use @ConditionalOnMissingBean. However it looks like this will work only when another bean of same "type" is not present. Is there a way to control this by using "name"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The annotation has the parameter name, where you can specify the bean name that should be checked:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "beanNameToCheck")
```

Comment: is it possible to use it in combination with the `value` parameter in order to check that there is no bean of type `Foo.class` with the name `beanNameToCheck` ? Currently when I add the value parameter, the condition is not matched if a bean of type `Foo.class` exists whether or not his name is `beanNameToCheck`